# sort excel file based on first column

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I Have a excel file as follow (with 2 columns - UserID and one varible):

```
variable                UserID
---------------------------------------
0.999999999999901       A3PPXVR5J6U2JD  
7.16184317895728e-10    A3RTKL9KB8KLID  
1.49736349513394e-16    AJVVATHEYX7L9   
5.57811370169348e-25    AOL7V6D4AL3KO   
1.49736349513394e-16    A214RU9GS37U2T  
0                       A2KJFH1F69U5R
4.45695014171021e-07    A38LAIK2N83NH0  
1.49736349513394e-16    A2P9YDRHZTJMC3  
1.49736349513394e-16    A1G2W2C669C8GC
.........
.
.
.
```

I want read this file in C# and sort based on column(1). I wrote this code:

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = myExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename: 
@"D:\test.xlsx");
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
xlrange.Sort(xlrange.Columns[1], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending);
```

I want take this result: (sort file based on column(1) in ascending)

```
0                       A2KJFH1F69U5R
5.57811370169348e-25    AOL7V6D4AL3KO
....
.
.
```

but this take columns as string and sort based on string . this mean that Code take column (1) as string and sort It. this answer is result of code:

```
0                       A2KJFH1F69U5R
0.999999999999901       A3PPXVR5J6U2JD  
1.49736349513394e-16    AJVVATHEYX7L9   
.
.
.
```

I want correct code that this code take first column as a double and sort file.

Comment: Here is all you need to know, add the Developer toolbar in Excel, click the record macro button, select column, **format cells**, select used range, sort, stop Recording, press Alt+F11 and convert the VBA to C#, it's quite easy as the object model is the same...

Comment: @JeremyThompson sorry I can not find what you say in my excel file

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=add+developer+tab+to+ribbon

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
        // VBA code goes here:
        excelApp.Columns["A:B"].Select
            excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Sort.SortFields.Clear
            excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range["A:B"], _
                SortOn:=Excel.XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues, Order:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, _
                DataOption:=Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal

            excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Sort.SetRange Range["A:B"]
            excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Sort.Header = Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlGuess
            excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Sort.MatchCase = False
            excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Sort.Orientation = Excel.Constants.xlTopToBottom
            excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Sort.SortMethod = Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin
            excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Sort.Apply

        excelApp.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/09/27/converting-a-vba-macro-to-c-4-0/).

Comment: @Eli  if this solved your problem. please upvote/accept it. thanks.